# Centered vertical rule in a displaymath

Tags: math-mode, rules

How would I place a *centered* vertical rule that separates two regions of text in a displaymath environoment? The effect I want is described below. Thanks!

```
\[
    3x + 2 = 6     | x + 5 = 7
    -2 = -2        |    -5 = -5
    3x = 4         | x = 2
    x = 4/3        |  
\]
```

Comment: Could we have a more explicit of what you want to obtain? (multilined maths or not, alignment points,&c.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! If it is text, why put it in a maths environment at all?

Comment: Edited. Hopefully more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
    $\begin{aligned}
    3x + 2 &= 6\\   
    -2 &= -2    \\    
    3x &= 4  \\       
    x &= 4/3  \\ 
    \end{aligned}$  &  
    $\begin{aligned}
    3x + 2 &= 6\\   
    -2 &= -2    \\    
    3x &= 4  \\       
    x &= 4/3  \\ 
    \end{aligned}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, I implement a tabular environment. You may also use an array or multicolumn version to create the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Without a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{aligned}
    3x + 2 &= 6\\
    -2 &= -2    \\
    3x &= 4  \\
    x &= 4/3  \\
    \end{aligned} \quad \vrule \quad
    \begin{aligned}
    3x + 2 &= 6\\
    -2 &= -2    \\
    3x &= 4  \\
    x &= 4/3  \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works too

```
\[
    \begin{aligned}
    3x + 2 &= 6\\
    -2 &= -2    \\
    3x &= 4  \\
    x &= 4/3  \\
    \end{aligned} \quad \vrule \quad
    \begin{aligned}
    3x + 2 &= 6\\
    -2 &= -2    \\
    3x &= 4  \\
    x &= 4/3  \\
    \end{aligned}
\]
```

Comment: Omg I totally forgot about `\vrule`